# How can I make this gray area go away (iOS UIKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

My iOS app, built with UIKit, has this gray area at the top and I don't know how to make it go away.  Here is the code for this screen:
[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulH4i.png)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class HomeController: UIViewController {
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    
    private let topStack = HomeNavigationStackView()
    private let bottomStack = BottomControlsStackView();
    
    private let deckView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        return view
    }()
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configureUI()
        configureCards()
        
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Helpers
 
    func configureCards(){
        let user1 = User(name: "Jane Doe", age: 22, images: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "jane1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "appSampleProfile")])
        let user2 = User(name: "Megan", age: 34, images: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "kelly2"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "appSampleProfile")])
        
        let cardView1 = CardView(viewModel: CardViewModel(user: user1))
        let cardView2 = CardView(viewModel: CardViewModel(user: user2))
        
        deckView.addSubview(cardView1)
        deckView.addSubview(cardView2)
        
        cardView1.fillSuperview()
        cardView2.fillSuperview()
        
        
    }
    
    func configureUI(){
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [topStack, deckView, bottomStack])
        stack.axis = .vertical
        
        
        view.addSubview(stack)
        stack.anchor(top:view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
        stack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stack.layoutMargins = .init(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 12)
        stack.bringSubviewToFront(deckView)
    }
    
    
}
```

And here is the code for the navigation items at the top:

```
import UIKit

class HomeNavigationStackView: UIStackView {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    let settingsButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let messageButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let tinderIcon = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "app_icon"))
    
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        tinderIcon.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        
        settingsButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "top_left_profile").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        messageButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "top_right_messages").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)

        
        
        [settingsButton, UIView(), tinderIcon, UIView(), messageButton].forEach{
            view in addArrangedSubview(view)
        }
        
        distribution = .equalCentering
        isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        layoutMargins = .init(top:0, left:16, bottom:0, right:16)
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: That is the Navigation bar.

Comment: You might have embedded `HomeController` in a Navigation view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: Your view controller is embedded in navigation controller

Comment: If the home view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, go to the storyboard file and delete the navigation controller and check the Initial view controller checkbox. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV9MA.png

Comment: You've embedded a navigation controller, you can't remove it but you can change its color

Answer (score 0):

you have embedded your view controller to a NavigationController in order to perform segues. You can hide the navigationBar and set your own Items like this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clear
navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Or if you want to leave it and the thing that bothers you is the shadow and gray color then you can use this code. It removes the shadow on the bottom of navigationBar (Gray Bar) and sets the backGrounColor to clear, but it leaves you ability to set the titleColor, tile etc.

```
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```